# Is it possible to get part of tableview cell to disappear by reducing it height at tableview delegates

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have a table view cell which has three elements vertically

- a title label
- a text box
- a validation label

I want to show validation label only when it fails.

If I just hide the validation label then the space occupied by the label is stil there and it looks awkward having more distance between the next row

so what would be the best approach to handle the scenario

- Change the table-row height whenever validation label's hidden status changes

  I think this approach probably will not work because label is still there in the tableview cell so the tableview cell will readjust itself to have the label height there irrespetive of whether it appears or not
- Change the label height constraint constant and tablerow height whenever there is change in label's hidden status

  so basically if I want to hide it then I will be setting the label's heigh to zero and readjust the tablerow height ... it'll work but there is a problem..

If I set label number of lines zero then depending on the content label will change its content height .... but as I am using constraint for height... I will be hardcoding the height and it can lead to problem again.

Basicallyy my need is I have one label and text box whose height is fixed and I have a one more label ... this could be hidden sometimes and this could be one line or 4 lines

I want the row height to adjust according to that(0 lines(hidden),1/2/3 line label visible)
sometime even the first label that I was talking it could go to the next line in smaller devices like iphone 4s

so somebody help me out on the issue

Comment: If you use a UIStackView, when you hide the label the stack view will re adjust to fit 2 items instead of and 3 and you will not have awkward space.

Comment: It is absolutely possible, but before diving into more interesting options, would simply putting the validation label to the right of the other two items be possible (and just toggle its visibility)?

Comment: @LoganHenderson - I have to support from iOS 8 so I can't use UIStackView

Comment: @conarch - No I have to keep it below the text field